# How to avoid command injection when using Twilio Say with user provided input?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

We have the following flow:

1. User has a call created in Twilio (browser or phone)
2. User types something on the website, like "Hello".
3. Using Twilio Say we want to say "Hello" in user's call, like `<Say>Hello</Say>`.
   Additionally, we want users to be able to submit SSML.

This works, but how do we prevent user from typing a valid TwiML command like: `Hello</Say><Redirect>https://example.com</Redirect><Say>Hello`.

In this case instructions that we send to Twilio are: `<Say>Hello</Say><Redirect>https://example.com</Redirect><Say>Hello</Say>` and the call will be redirected to user specified site.

In HTML the way to avoid this type of injection is to encode user-provided input using HTML encoding.

This works with normal text, but if user provides SSML then Twilio does not recognize it as valid SSML after encoding.

The only other way that I see to avoid injection is to inject the user input directly between `<Say>` tags without encoding, but before validate that it's either a string or a valid SSML that does not contain any Twilio tags within.

Are there any other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

> The only other way that I see to avoid injection is to inject the user input directly between  tags without encoding, but before validate that it's either a string or a valid SSML that does not contain any Twilio tags within.

This sounds like the right approach to me.